# Apache Service detected with wrong path and not starting

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Good day,
I just started the PHP course and downloaded XAMPP to try out my codes but I always get  the following error message as soon as i open the XAMPP Control Panel

> 9:54:48 PM  [Apache]  Apache Service detected with wrong path
>
> 9:54:48 PM  [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
>
> 9:54:48 PM  [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>
> 9:54:48 PM  [Apache]  Found Path: "c:\pm_server\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>
> 9:54:48 PM  [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>
> 9:54:48 PM  [mysql]   XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306

[Net Command always launches whenever i click the start button for Apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFFjO.png)

And the Net Command always launches whenever i click the start button for Apache which ends up doing Nothing.

I'd really appreciate if someone helps me out on how to successfully start the Apache

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would take a guess you have another web server running and it has already captured port 80 for its own use

Comment: This shoudl really be giving you that clue `pm_server\apache\bin\httpd.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You already have an Apache instance running in your background as a service. If you still want to keep the Apache installed in your `c:\pm_server\apache\bin\` but you want to use the apache that is bundled together in XAMPP. Follow this step:

1. Ctrl + R and type regedit then enter
2. Open this directory
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Apache2.4
3. Right-click on the "ImagePath" and choose "Modify"
4. Change the Value Data field with your current installed path of
   apache in XAMPP
5. In my case, the value should be changed to `"D:\apps\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k
   runservice`
6. For the question poster case, change the value to
   `"c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice`

As for the Net Command, it pops up because you run the XAMPP application not as Administrator